# Spark Streaming - Diagnostics: Container is running beyond physical memory limits

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-2.0

My Spark Streaming job failed with the below exception

> Diagnostics: Container is running beyond physical memory limits.
>   Current usage: 1.5 GB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 3.6 GB of 3.1 GB
>   virtual memory used. Killing container.

Here is my spark submit command

```
spark2-submit \
--name App name \
--class Class name \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--queue Queue name \
--num-executors 5 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 5G \
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer \
--conf spark.locality.wait=10 \
--conf spark.task.maxFailures=8 \
--conf spark.ui.killEnabled=false \
--conf spark.logConf=true \
--conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=512 \
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048 \
--conf spark.yarn.max.executor.failures=40 \
jar path
```

I am not sure what's causing the above issue. Am I missing something in the above command or is it failing as I didn't set **--driver-memory** in my spark submit command?

Comment: I'd first check the Environment tab of the Spark app as you may have different settings applied to this failing execution. Given the command line I can't find why you got _"3.6 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used."_

Comment: Would it be because of any default configs?

Comment: I added --driver-memory 5G to the above spark submit command and the issue seems to be resolved. But, I am still not sure how it is linked to physical memory.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the Environment tab from web UI before and after the change? That'd be very helpful. I'm still unsure why you got 1.5 GB for the driver by default. Looks like your Spark app does a lot of `collect`s. I'd monitor the driver's JVM.